# SQL server connection error from VB6 code

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, vb6

In my company there is small project developed in vb6.
it is working fine but some time it gives following error and schedule stop working

[image]

We are using Sql server 2008 R2 and Windows server 2003 enterprise edition and this strange error is not coming frequently.
It is coming only 2-3 times in month. Schedule for this project is run for every 4 min.
So what can be problem? Most of time it is running Properly. so why sometime it is giving some error.

And this project/.EXE was made 7-8 years ago and has been working fine so far. This error is coming form last 4 month other wise before that,it was working fine.

Comment: Some intermittent network problem?

Comment: @Arvo : I guess no network problem.. because there are some other vb project referring other SQL database in same database server  is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

your program is running in windows server or another system?.

Sometime windows "thinks" that your program is a virus, to avoid this just add it in [**Data Execution Prevention** (DEP)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Change-Data-Execution-Prevention-settings?SignedIn=1)

Comment: both my program and Database is in same server windows server 2003